# How do I forget or change the username and password for file sharing?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, smb, file-sharing

1. I connected my MacBook (macOS 10.13 if it matters) to my Mac Pro fileshare using the username ***foo*** and the password. I tell Finder to save the password.
2. I want to disconnect from that server and login again but this time with username ***bar*** and ***bar***'s password.

Here's the problem: as soon as I press the Disconnect button in the Finder on my MacBook, it immediately reconnects as user ***foo***. It does not stay disconnected.

How can I connect to an existing server with a different username and password?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Finder’s **Go** menu and choose **Utilities**
2. Select **Keychain Acces**
3. Select the Login Keychain then select the **network password** or **internet password** for the printers and/or shares.
4. Hold down the “control” key and click the keychain entry. Select Delete.

Now, access your network resource (printer or share) and re-enter your new username and password when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

On my macOS Ventura:

1. Open Finder.
2. Press `Go` on the top menu bar.
3. Choose `Utilities`.
4. In the opened window double click on `Keychain Access`.
5. In Keychain Access, select the Passwords category on the *top right* bar to review the list of sites and services for which you've saved a password.
6. Right-click the service you want to remove, then click Delete.